# Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift

In my code, I get the following errors:
`// cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'String'` and
`// Extra argument 'error' in call`

```
class ScoreManager {
var scores:Array<Score> = [];

init() {
    // load existing high scores or set up an empty array
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let path = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Scores.plist")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    // check if file exists
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) { // cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'String'
        // create an empty file if it doesn't exist
        if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DefaultFile", ofType: "plist") {
            fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path, error:nil) // Extra argument 'error' in call
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to implement Swift 2 do try catch error handling

Comment: BTW naming a NSURL `path` is totally misleading change it to `let scoreURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Scores.plist")` and if you need the path just use `scoreURL.path!`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating path as a NSURL (which is what `URLByAppendingPathComponent` returns), but `fileExistsAtPath` takes a string representation of the path as a parameter. TheNSURL's `path` property will give you this...

```
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path.path!)
```

Regarding `copyItemAtPath`, you are probably looking at the Objective-C signature rather than the Swift one. For Swift it's:

```
func copyItemAtPath(_ srcPath: String,
         toPath dstPath: String) throws
```

Therefore you would use `do/try` to catch the exception it may throw.

Comment: NSURL path property returns an optional String

Answer (score 0):

As the errors are telling you, you need to call `fileManager.fileExistsAtPath:` with a `String` not an `NSURL`.

Additionally, Swift does not use the `error` callback, instead it uses `do/catch`

Applied, the fixes look like so:

```
init() {
    // load existing high scores or set up an empty array
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let path = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Scores.plist")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    // check if file exists
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
        // create an empty file if it doesn't exist
        if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DefaultFile", ofType: "plist") {
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path)
            } catch {

            }
        }
    }
}
```